# Destroy redirect in Controller Rails Shallow Routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I have a simple rails model Project which has many Tasks. I am trying to learn proper shallow routes but very little is explained when it comes to controller tasks in most tutorials. My issue is that I have everything working except the Destroy part.

Routes

```
resources :projects, shallow: true do
   resources :tasks do
end
```

Models

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tasks, dependent: :destroy
end

class Project < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :projects
end
```

Then I have simple controllers generated by scaffolding. I have added references to projects on the tasks table.

I have followed Digital Oceans guide on how to nest resources but nowhere can I find a comprehensive shallow tutorial that covers Controllers and Views in addition.

So I have all the other functions working like show, edit, update etc. Not sure how I got them working but by changing word orders and adding in pieces it works... Horray me. But now I cannot get it to route back to the Tasks index(which has the project ID) URL which would be projects/id/tasks/ after I hit destroy. I keep getting error ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in TasksController#edit and rails is highlighting this part as my error issue:

```
def set_task
   @task = Task.find(params[:id])
end
```

I know this was default generated by the scaffolding and the only part I added prior to is the before action get_project and this:

```
def get_project
  @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
end
```

Any ideas would be greatly helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found my solution thinking about it more it was really a redirect issue and that the controller was not grabbing the parent ID from the child controller in the destroy routing. So after fiddling with this more and more I found my answer to change my destroy redirect from:

```
redirect_to project_scene_headings_path(@project)
```

to

```
redirect_to project_scene_headings_path(@scene_heading.project_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are passing the `project_id` parameter while hitting the `edit` route. If it is not relevant for the edit route, you can add a condition to skip the `before_action` for the edit route:

```
before_action :get_project, except: [:edit]
```

Comment: I already  had something like that by using before_action :get_project, only: [:index, :new, :create]. This did not work unfortunately. The issue seems like its not re-routing to the projects/id/scene_heading url. The URL is still keeping the shortened version of localhost/scene_heading/id while still trying to call for that specific id of the deleted entry. The rails console shows it getting deleted showing this error: ActionController::UrlGenerationError (No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"scene_headings", :project_id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:project_id]):